# Missing "Office 365 Management APIs" from Azure AD - Enterprise Applications

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365

I'm struggling currently to register a few Enterprise Applications within an Azure AD tenant. Upon further investigation it seems the common theme is that they all require access into the "Office 365 Management APIs".

From what I understand that API is available to all AzureAD tenants upon creation. I can certainly see that API in all my other tenants that I have access to.

For reason unknown to me it simply isn't present in one specific tenant I'm attempting to work with.

The ApplicationID is : 19d8051e-de0f-4f13-89bf-c90814bcc0f4

On another tenant where the API exists (and I can register the Applications) I can search and find the API.

My question I guess is, is there a way to get the APIs available to the problem tenant?

Thank you!

Edit : updated screenshots:
[Result from trying to consent access to Office 365 Management APIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB2jN.png)

Edit2 : When running Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "office 365 management APIs" | Format-Table serviceprincipalnames it returns NULL on the tenant, this returns results on a working tenant.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, every tenant should have this api. Is your application registered in this tenant?

Go to **Azure AD**>**App registrations**>**New registration** to register your application (the application will also be displayed in the **enterprise application**). Then select the **application you registered**>**API permissions**>**Add a permission** and you will be able to see `Office 365 Management APIs`.

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.).This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Carl, Thank you so much for your reply. I'm unable to add the Application as it required the API to register from the 3rd party however on a TestApp I can see Management APIs as an option for Permissions. However when granting delegated permissions it will fail (probably because the API doesn't exist on the tenant).

Comment: The error when trying to allow the API permissions come back : Grant consent failed with error: Application 'xxx-xx-xx' is requesting permissions that are either invalid or out of date.

Comment: @Chris_UK2021  Can you provide some screenshots?

Comment: Hi @Carl, I have updated original post with edits for you :)

Comment: @Chris_UK2021  Is this a bug only for `Office 365 Management APIs`? If you delete the permission and then grant the admin consent, will an error be reported?

Comment: If we delete the permission and grant all is fine, if we add the Office 365 Management API onto any App Reg and attempt to grant it hits that failure. @MS seem to be stumped too they can't understand why that core API is missing from the tenant!

Comment: @Chris_UK2021  Do you mean that you delete the permission first, and then add it again to work?

Comment: Any reference to that API simply doesn't work, no Enterprise App can be installed/added and no permission that leverages that API will work as it simply doesn't exist on the tenant.